# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.isPublicStaticFinal(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)Z

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar

After application deployment in websphere application server v8,I'm getting the above error on JVM startup.MANIFEST.MF file contains two jars spring-2.5.5.jar & spring-sandbox.jar (version 1.2) and the said method "isPublicStaticFinal" is not present in spring-sandbox.jar but it's present in spring-2.5.5.jar (both having same package with same class i.e.org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils) I guess there's something with version mismatch or conflict between two classes in the jars.I'm not able to get the latest version of sandbox jar.Also, I can't remove that jar as application is using some functions in that jar.Does entries/order of jars in classpath of MANAIFEST.MF matters? Any solution for this please?

Comment: well if u can't remove class or jars....the first workaround coming to my mind id to rename the jar name in order that classloader loads first spring2.5.5 and then sandbox..tray to rename the spring2.5.5 jar in aspring-2.5.5; in any case, IMHO, the best solution is to have no class conflict....so yuo should try to avoid to have 2 classes with same full qulified name in different jars....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Angelo.It is working fine now.

I have re-ordered the classpath enteries in Manifest.mf so that it loads first jar where the class and method is available.So, this is my conclusion now..order of jars matters in Manifest specially when two jars contains same class with same method and same package indeed.